# Java package convention

Tags: java, android, package

I'm developing an Android project which currently has 4 packages:

```
com.myapp.app.activities
com.myapp.app.db
com.myapp.app.ws
com.myapp.app.utils
```

Would I be able to create an additional package which is just

```
com.myapp.app
```

?

Eclipse isn't letting me create this package.  It tells me a package with this name already exists.

If I start a new project and create a package called "com.testing.app" and then create a new package called "com.testing.app.activities" afterward, it works fine.

For Android developers:

What I'm wanting to do is extend the Application class and have it in a separate package.  Suppose com.myapp.app can't be used, what's a good name for this new package?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eclipse won't let you create this package because it already exists.

Packages in Java are represented in the filesystem as hierarchical folders: `com.myapp.app.activities` is in the `com/myapp/app/activities` folder. `com/myapp/app` already exists, so you can't create this package.

In Eclipse, juste create a new class, and in the "Package" section, precise you want to create it in the `com.myapp.app` package. This should work.

Answer (score 3):

The package `com.myapp.app` already exists. You can create a class named `com.myapp.app.MyClass`, you'll see it right in the `app` package.

Another thing you can do is changing the layout of your packages from a flat layout to a hierarchical layout :

[image: Example]

---

**Resources :**

- [help.eclipse.org : Project Explorer view](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-27.htm)

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using that this isn't default?

Comment: @Falmarri I don't use eclipse (personal convictions :P) but you don't have to always install your own eclipse, sometimes you just get a preconfigured one and these settings can be modified on the "custom" version.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse by default hides empty packages. In the package explorer view, click at the small arrow in the right top: *View Menu*. Choose *Customize View*. In the *Filters* tab you need to uncheck *Empty packages*. Now empty packages will be visible in the package explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that if I manually place a file into the directory and refresh the package explorer in Eclipse, the new com.myapp.app package appears